# How to use Bazel to build third party c++ library that includes openssl?

Tags: c++, bazel

So long story short, I am trying to use Bazel to build a project on OSX that depends on [uWebSockets](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets). I am running into a problem with how to add openssl as a dependency so that files in uWebSockets are able to include files from openssl like so:

```
#include <openssl/opensslv.h>
```

My WORKSPACE file in the repo looks like(it looks for openssl installed via homebrew):

```
new_http_archive(
    name = "uwebsockets",
    urls = ["https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets/archive/master.zip"],
    build_file = "BUILD.uWebSockets",
)

new_local_repository(
    name = "systemssl",
    path = "/usr/local/opt/openssl",
    build_file = "BUILD.systemssl",
)
```

BUILD.uWebSockets:

```
cc_library(
    name = "uwebsockets-lib",
    hdrs = glob(["**/src/*.h"]),
    srcs = glob(["**/src/*.cpp"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "@systemssl//:openssl",
    ],
)
```

BUILD.systemssl:

```
cc_library(
    name = "openssl",
    hdrs = glob(["**/openssl/*.h"]),
    srcs = glob([
        "**/libssl.a",
        "**/libcrypto.a",
    ]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Whenever I try to run the build, everything builds correctly but I get:

```
external/uwebsockets/uWebSockets-master/src/Networking.h:7:10: fatal error: 'openssl/opensslv.h' file not found
```

I must be missing something here, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an "includes" attribute in the BUILD.systemssl file for the correct include path for anything depending on the library.

Is there a reason why your glob starts with "**" is it because the version number is encoded in the file path? You should also look into the "strip_prefix" attribute that you can use for new_local_repository in your WORKSPACE file to strip that away.